# How to post the_content when the id is being passed to URL

Tags: php, wordpress

So i have a local install of wordpress, using my own front page, and single page blog post.  what i want to do is get to the single blog post using the post id. This is as far as i've got - but when the link is clicked i get nothing.

The url passed from the a href looks ok - blogpost.php?postid=1 i just need it to pull the blog post data using that id if that makes sense?

```
<?php
    global $post;
    $args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 3 );
    $myposts = get_posts( $args );
    foreach( $myposts as $post ) :  setup_postdata($post); ?>
    <div class="col-sm-4" style="padding-left:50px; padding-right:50px;">
    <div class="media">
        <a href="blogpost.php?postid=<?php echo $id; ?>"><?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'single-post-thumbnail' ); ?>
        <div id="custom-bg" style="background-image: url('<?php echo $image[0]; ?>'); background-size:cover;">
        <h1 style="padding:50px;"><?php the_title(); ?></h1></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="media-body" style="background-color:white; padding:20px;">
        <h4 style="color:#000"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></h4>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Where are you populating the variable $id? Are you sure it has the content you expect? Might be worth doing a var_dump on it to check.

Comment: i believe this is from setup_postdata, i have had this working but now i cant find the page that it links to so i have half of the work if you like, the part im missing is on the page it goes to (blogpost.php) and how to pull a partifucular blog post using the ID from the Url

Comment: Please think how you would explain this problem from scratch to a coworker who was helping you, and edit the question accordingly. Thanks. I really don't understand your comment just posted, and I am unconvinced that a wordpress subject matter expert would either.

Comment: ok ill try and re-explain.

I have a page i built myself, at the bottom of the page i used the above code to pull the last 3 blog posts from wordpress which is installed locally. 

I then passed the Post ID to a URL using <a href="blogpost.php?postid=<?php echo $id; ?>">

when i click that link on my homepage i have a blogpost page that i built myself, but it doesnt pull the blog post data across even though the Url itself is correct (the id is 1 cause theres only 1 post)

so in basic terminology i want to pull the_content() where id = $id (from the url)

Comment: Thanks. Please now edit the question to provide this added clarification, which will make it more likely that someone will spot this and help you. Also please edit the source code so that we don't have to scroll horizontally to read it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out

```
<?php
$post = $_GET['postid'];
$image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'single-post-thumbnail' );
?>
<img src="<?php echo $image[0]; ?>" height=100% width=100%>
<h1 style="padding:50px;"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
</div>
<?php>
$post = $_GET['postid'];  
$include = get_posts("include=$post");
$content = apply_filters('the_content',$include[0]->post_content);
echo $content;
?>
```